# Should I edit the legacy name if its owner has change to a new username?

Tags: discussion, edits, display-names

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5187/245360):

> [image: image description]

It is highly in doubt that @Robert Cartaino used to be @rcar. Should I edit this?

Comment: Is that bit needed in the answer?

Comment: Seems to me Robert didn't even mention using `<sub>`, so it's just confusing. (If the comment was changed, [the pencil should show even for a moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66386/can-anyone-at-all-edit-my-comments/66387#66387)?) So in this case I'd remove the reference, not change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you don't have to. You can even remove it I think since it doesn't look very necessary (maybe a reply to a comment or small attribution).

If you want to improve that post and make it easier to understand: go ahead. Fix it. Make sure to fix all possible issues, or some reviewers may decline it for such a small change.

Also I could argue it isn't very necessary, but a small improvement *is* an improvement.