# Indicate or limit character capacity in custom comment textarea of review modal

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, character-limit

I was reviewing a first question from a new user today in the review queue and wrote a custom comment that was evidently too long.

At the time of writing, I didn't realize that I exceeded the character limit in the comment field because there was no indication in the UI.  The modal allowed me to submit my lengthy comment and closed the modal.

When I revisited the question later in the day, I discovered that my generous feedback was silently truncated. (Fortunately, I could repair my comment with my [mod super-powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66387/352329).)

Could we please either have an indication of characters used and the limit? An alternative feature would be for the textarea to be character limited so that we don't have a false sense of character capacity.

Comment: Huh, there is, indeed, no client-side validation done on how long can the message be - can you, if you still remember the post and the comment, clarify what the exact limit is? Will add to the FAQ :)

Comment: Realted [A[n] [In]complete Character-Limiting Guide to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372184)

Comment: I feel like it was around about 600.  I'll confirm when the opportunity arises. @Oleg

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks! I will try to do so on my side too, but I am quite wary of the queue and especially of the "leave feedback" choice...

Comment: Re *"in the review queue"*: But not on this site? *"mod superpowers"* may suggest it isn't (or was just superpowers in a more abstract sense (not literal)?). Perhaps elaborate a little bit in question?

Comment: @This As a moderator on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange,  I am granted the privilege to edit any comment at any time (in that community).